# Multi RDP connections as an Admin to the domain controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, connection

We have a 2008 r2 server that's everything in one.  It's a domain controller plus it runs some applications.  I know it's a not a good design but it is what it is.

Since it's a domain controller, it has restrictions on who can access it via RDP.  I added bunch of folks to the domain administrator group.  When the users login they bump each other off (these are different users with different login and password).  It appears that there is only one connection as an admin allowed on the domain controller(?).

The questions is, how can I allow multiple-admin-RDP-connection to the domain controller?  Please note that the server is fully licensed up to five connections (which is the number of users that I have).

**Edit**
Folks, the Remote Desktop Session Host is on and the License Server is also running.  The license that I mentioned WAS for RDS Not windows.  We have five licenses.

We are having issues running more than one RemoteApp at the same time to same server.  RemoteApp relies on RDS.  Currently, only an administrator can launch the RemoteApp. I suspect this is due to the fact that the server is also a DC.  We need to be able to run five connections at the same time all running the RemoteApp.  I hope this clarifies things a bit.

If were you guys reading this I would be throwing insults too.  But just take it from me...again...it is what it is.

**Update**  Thank you everyone.  We demoted the server from DC and now everything works fine.  We now can have multi connections at the same time.  For the next foolio -> if it's a DC, only administrators can RDP to DC.

Comment: Having the DC run a few extra services is one thing; it's no one's first choice, but we've all done it. Putting standard users into the Domain Admin group is whole other league of stupid.

Comment: Please see my edits and any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753380.aspx it should help you.

By default the number should be two connections.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum you can have is two simultaneously, *unless* you enable the RD Session Host feature. Note: RDS CALs are different from windows CALs. There's no need to have the users in the domain admins group.

Comment: We are talking about RDS CALs..not windows.  RD SEssion host is turned on.  The license server is running and has five RDS licences.  Thanks

Comment: @Zuzlx Ah, I see; that would make a difference. IMO it sounds like a good reason to take it to management and get the resources to take the app/users off the DC.

Answer (score 0):

Questionable administrative group practices aside, you can get into a third session by launching mstsc with /admin.

```
mstsc /admin
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum simultaneous allowed RDP connectons is two regardless of being a domain admin or not. I would never add non admin users to the domain admins group.

To allow more than two connections you can make your server a terminal services server - add that service, and requires licesing as well.

The licensing you are talkig about has nothing to do with RDP, it is the number of people who can logon to your domain at the same time.(someone correct me if I'm wrong).